# Add data to database

Tags: magento-1.8, database, sql

Im trying to add some data to a database i just created.

Here is the database.
It works fine!

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$sql=<<<SQLTEXT
create table emailorders(
    emailorders_id int not null auto_increment, 
    order_date varchar(255) not null,
    product_name varchar(255) not null,
    location varchar(255) not null,
    date_for varchar(255) not null,
    name_title varchar(100) not null,
    email varchar(255) not null,
    company varchar(255) not null,
    adress varchar(255) not null,
    zipcode varchar(255) not null,
    city varchar(255) not null,
    phone varchar(255) not null,
    comment text not null,
    order_done int not null default 0,
    primary key(emailorders_id)

);


SQLTEXT;

$installer->run($sql);
//demo 
//Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->setId(null);
//demo 
$installer->endSetup();
```

Here are the code when i try to add the data to det created database

```
<?php 
$details = $this->getDetails();
$conferance_name = $details['product_name'];
$hotel = $details['hotelval'];
$date = $details['dateval'];
$ogtitel = $details['navn_title'];
$virksomhed = $details['virksomhed'];
$adresse = $details['adresse'];
$postnr = $details['postnr'];
$by = $details['by'];
$telefon = $details['telefon'];
$email = $details['email'];
$kommentarer = $details['kommentarer'];
$newdate = date('Y-m-d')


?>

<?php


$sql = "INSERT INTO emailorders (order_date, product_name, location, date_for, name_title, email, company, adress, zipcode, city, phone, comment, order_done)
VALUES ('$newdate', $conferance_name', '$hotel', $date, '$ogtitel', '$email', '$virksomhed', '$adresse', '$postnr', '$by', '$telefon', '$kommentarer','0')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

All my variables works, i have echo them to check. But why is the data not going in the database? :(

Hope you can help

***UPDATE!***

I just tried this with the same result :(

```
  <?php

$cron = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$query = "INSERT INTO emailorders (emailorders_id, order_date, product_name, location, date_for, name_title, email, company, adress, zipcode, city, phone, comment, order_done)
VALUES (NULL, '$newdate', $conferance_name', '$hotel', '$date', '$ogtitel', '$email', '$virksomhed', '$adresse', '$postnr', '$by', '$telefon', '$kommentarer', '0')";

try {
    $cron->query($query);
    echo "New record created successfully";
} catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
       echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" .$e->getMessage());
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas...

First of all, your variable `$conn` should be a write resource, for instance

```
$conn = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
```

Second, after executing your SQL script, and validating the DB table exists, be sure to clean Magento cache filesystem (this is: remove the content of var/cache, it is not enough to flush cache through the backoffice buttons, when database have changed. Although I suppose this applies only when using Magento models to interact with database, which is not the case)

Finally, I think you are missing the first value in your `INSERT` query. It should be NULL, for the autoincrement field

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO emailorders VALUES (NULL, etc...
```

Be careful with the quotes in the SQL statement. You should quote all non numeric fields

**UPDATE**

Try this code to see the concrete error

```
// $sql is your insert query    
try {
    $conn = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
    $conn->query($sql);
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Just tried what you said nothing :( But yeah i forgot the NULL in the start. good eyes :P any more ideas?

Comment: What's the concrete error?

Comment: I did not ment an error, it's just the same as before.

Comment: Code should throw an error if it does not work; execute it in a try/catch block, and report the concrete error. If not, no one could help you

Comment: im sorry i dont know how :( Is there a guide to do so?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a try/catch example, maybe you should enable error_reporting in your webserver

Comment: Soory :P 
here is what i get. 
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Medier og Online Marketing', 'København ', '27. september 2016', 'Testnavn', 't' at line 2

Comment: Can you paste your query as it is? Just execute echo $sql and paste the result here. If your query is the same you've posted in your first post, then you have missed a single quote at the start of the param $conferance_name

Comment: This is the result 
INSERT INTO emailorders (emailorders_id, order_date, product_name, location, date_for, name_title, email, company, adress, zipcode, city, phone, comment, order_done) VALUES (NULL, '2016-01-29', Sociale Medier og Online Marketing', 'København ', '8. marts 2016', 'Testnavn', 'testemail', 'testvirksomhed', 'testadresse', 'testpostnummer', 'testby', 'testtelefon', 'TEST FRA IT!', '0')

Comment: As I've commented before, check the quotes. There is a missing single quote: ... 'Sociale Medier og Online Marketing', ...

Answer (score 0):

- First,You need to create a model for this module.
- then Create *a folder* `(name: data)` at your module  dir 
  `app/code/YOUR_CODEPOOL/ModuleNameSpace/ModuleName/data/YOUR_SETUP_FolderName/`.

Here,you create file `Data-upgrade-YourCurrentVersin-ChangeVersion.php`.

And put your data code.Alos change Vetsion at config.xml

See [how use in data-install-scripts](http://inchoo.net/magento/using-magento-1-6-data-install-scripts/)

Comment: can you plz explain it a bit more? :)

Comment: little  bit of bust now..Will be reply soon

Comment: okey. hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php 
$details = $this->getDetails();
$conferance_name = $details['product_name'];
$hotel = $details['hotelval'];
$date = $details['dateval'];
$ogtitel = $details['navn_title'];
$virksomhed = $details['virksomhed'];
$adresse = $details['adresse'];
$postnr = $details['postnr'];
$by = $details['by'];
$telefon = $details['telefon'];
$email = $details['email'];
$kommentarer = $details['kommentarer'];
$newdate = date('Y-m-d')


?>

<?php

$writeAdapter = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$query = "INSERT INTO emailorders (order_date, product_name, location, date_for, name_title, email, company, adress, zipcode, city, phone, comment, order_done)
VALUES ('".$newdate."', '".$conferance_name."', '".$hotel."', '".$date."','".$ogtitel."', '".$email."', '".$virksomhed."', '".$adresse."', '".$postnr."', '".$by."', '".$telefon."', '".$kommentarer."','0')";


try {
    $writeAdapter->query($query);
    echo "New record created successfully";
} catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
       echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" .$e->getMessage());
}


?>
```

Comment: Just tried. no luck :(